# big O growth function of binomial coefficient C(r,k) in Concrete Mathematics book on page 163

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am reading "Concrete Mathematics" book about the convergence proof of binomial theorem, on page 163, it says "...It does. Because $ \binom r k = O(k^{-1-r}) $ by equation (5.83) below...", here $r$ is arbitrary and $k$ is an integer.

For reference, on page 210, equation (5.83) is given as $\frac{1}{z!} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \binom {n+z} n n^{-z}$.

Can anyone please explain how is $\binom r k = O (k^{-1-r})$ derived from equation (5.83) as above?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$r^{\underline{k}} = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (r-i) = (-1)^k \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (i-r)
= (-1)^k (k-1-r)^{\underline{k}}$$

Therefore

$$\binom{r}{k} = \frac{r^{\underline{k}}}{k!} = (-1)^k \binom{k-1-r}{k}$$

Now (5.83) implies

$$\binom{k+z}{k} = \operatorname{O}(k^z)
\quad\text{as}\quad k\to\infty$$

Plugging in $z = -1-r$ leads to the stated result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.